# Auto-Complete/Primary Key as String - PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I setup a database that is not too complex but still nonetheless has multiple many-to-many relationships.  Let me explain the database first briefly using three tables(there are many more, but just to keep things simple):

Database is storing information about projects completed.  One attribute is software used.  So I have three tables(with respective columns/keys):

tblProjects(ProjectID[PK], ProjectTitle, etc...)

tblProjectsSoftware(SoftwareID[FK], ProjectID[FK], UniqueID[PK])

tblSoftwareUsed(SoftwareID[PK], SoftwareName)

In order to make data entry easier in phppgadmin, I was considering just making 'SoftwareName' the primary key in tblSoftwareUsed.  This is because when I go to enter the software associated with certain projects into tblProjectsSoftware, I can only use the auto-complete feature on the SoftwareID column which is just more or less a meaningless number.

[image]

As you can see, when entering data into the SoftwareID column of tblSoftwareUsed, I would only be able to 'filter' results by the ID and not the name.  When this database gets large, it may not be an issue for software, but there are some other attributes that will have tons of records.  To explain that further, I would start my data entry by creating a record for the project in tblProjects.  Then I would create new records (if necessary) for software used.  Then, when entering data into tblProjectsSoftware, I would either have to know the ID of the software or click through a few pages to find it.

So, my question is, would I have any issues by making the name of the software my Primary Key, or would it be better to just leave it as is with the ID as the PK?  Furthermore, maybe I am missing an option to make 'SoftwareName' searchable as in addition to the ID.

Comment: Well, if you were writing it yourself, you just make the name another unique (or not) key-- looks like you're more asking about features of phppgadmin though. Writing a web app to do what you appear to be doing would be pretty trivial though.

Comment: I am not looking to write something new.  I'm just wondering if it's a bad idea to make a string a PK in this case OR if there is some other way to get what I want using phppgadmin.

Comment: Using a string for a PK is not without drawbacks. #1, if you use a numeric PK, then if you change the title of your product, you don't wind up with a huge headache updating all your data. Also, in a web app, you can pass around numbers easily without worrying about text screwing up form fields, urls or anything else. It just creates more headaches to use text for PKs on tables like this. Now, on a base table like a "state" or for a few statuses, I'd have no problem because you know the issues when you insert the (very limited) data.

Comment: This will be for a web app so based on what you said it would probably be best to just keep it numeric. There has to be a way to make the other field searchable as well...I'll have to do some more digging.

Comment: The answer may be either modify phppgadmin, or write your own scaffolding app -- they're really not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

There are advantages and disadvantages to using surrogate keys, which are discussed at length in this wikipedia article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

Borrowing their headers...

> Advantages:
>
> - Immutability
> - Requirement changes
> - Performance
> - Compatibility
> - Uniformity
> - Validation
>
> Disadvantages:
>
> - Disassociation
> - Query optimization
> - Normalization
> - Business process modeling
> - Inadvertent disclosure
> - Inadvertent assumptions

More often than not, you'll want to use a surrogate key for practical reasons -- such as avoiding headaches when you need to update a software name.